# How to get IQueryable<T> from IQueryable<IQueryable<T>>?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, iqueryable

I am trying to get a `PagedList` of `Order`s from a vender. It has `ICollection` of `Order`s.

`CreateAsync` method requires `IQueryable` of `Order`s but I have `IQueryable` of `Vender`s ??

```cs
public async Task<PagedList<Order>> GetVenderOrders(int venderId, OrderParams orderParams)
{
    var vender = _dataContext.Venders.Include(v => v.Orders)
        .ThenInclude(o => o.RentedCar).Where(v => v.VenderId == venderId);

    var orders = vender.Select(x => x.Orders.AsQueryable());

    return await PagedList<Order>.CreateAsync(orders, orderParams.PageNumber, orderParams.PageSize);
}

public static async Task<PagedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
    var count = await source.CountAsync();
    var items = await source.Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
    return new PagedList<T>(items, count, pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The fix to this problem is by using SelectMany instead of Select.**

**Select:** return An IQueryable whose elements are the result of invoking a projection function on each element of source.

**SelectMany:** An IQueryable whose elements are the result of invoking the one-to-many projection function collectionSelector on each element of source and then mapping each of those sequence elements and their corresponding source element to a result element.

```
public async Task<PagedList<Order>> GetVenderOrders(int venderId, OrderParams orderParams)
        {
            var orders = _dataContext.Venders.Include(v => v.Orders)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.RentedCar).Where(v => v.VenderId == venderId)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Orders);


            return await PagedList<Order>.CreateAsync(orders ,orderParams.PageNumber, orderParams.PageSize);
            
        }
```

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow. You are absolutely right with `SelectMany`. Please amend this answer with the fixed code and marked your own answer as THE answer to close this topic properly.